# text to the right of an equation

Tags: equations, align, text

I would like to do something like this in my document.
[image]
[image]

The red line can have different type like --[
___|--

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to use the enviroment `align*` for example. Here I have not used the `geometry` package and I have not put others `&` to increase the distance of the text or the formulas.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
&\int \sinh(x) \ dx=\cosh(x)+c &&& \text{right text}\\
&\int \cosh(x) \ dx=-\sinh(x)+c &&& \text{another right text}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here there is another example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
&\int \sinh(x) \ dx=\cosh(x)+c &&& \int \sinh(x) \ dx=\cosh(x)+c\\
&\int \cosh(x) \ dx=-\sinh(x)+c &&& \int \sinh(x) \ dx=\cosh(x)+c
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `geometry` package and others `&`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
&\int \sinh(x) \ dx=\cosh(x)+c &&&\text{since}& \int \sinh(x) \ dx=\cosh(x)+c\\
&\int \cosh(x) \ dx=-\sinh(x)+c &&&\text{since}& \int \sinh(x) \ dx=\cosh(x)+c
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Addendum:

A simple trick could be to put the `\bullet` command. It is more simple I should to change the whole code)...otherwise you can ask a new question.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\bullet\,&\int \sinh(x) \ dx=\cosh(x)+c &&&\text{since}& \int \sinh(x) \ dx=\cosh(x)+c\\
\bullet\,&\int \cosh(x) \ dx=-\sinh(x)+c &&&\text{since}& \int \sinh(x) \ dx=\cosh(x)+c
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, but I would like to have it inside an \begin{itemize} like in the image.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `alignat` environment in order to not have quite that much whitespace:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\arsinh{\mathop{\operator@font arsinh}\nolimits}
\newcommand*\arcosh{\mathop{\operator@font arcosh}\nolimits}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{4}
\int \sinh x \, dx & = \cosh x + c & \qquad & \text{since} & \quad & \frac d{dx} (\cosh x) && = \sinh x \\
\int \cosh x \, dx & = \sinh x + c && \text{since} && \frac d{dx} (\sinh x) && = \cosh x \\
\int \frac1{ \sqrt{ 1 + x^2 }} \, dx & = \arsinh x + c && \text{since} && \frac d{dx} (\arsinh x) && = \frac1{ \sqrt{1 + x^2 }} \\
\int \frac1{ \sqrt{ x^2 - 1 }} \, dx & = \arcosh x + c,\ x > 1 && \text{since} && \frac d{dx} (\arcosh x) && = \frac1{ \sqrt{x^2 - 1 }},\ x > 1
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can add bullets manually, as Sebastiano suggested in the amendment to his answer; I'm not sure whether `itemize` and aligning (parts of) equations otherwise works.

Comment: Approved totally :-) +1

Comment: @Sebastiano thanks, and you got a +1 from me as well. :)

Comment: I am very happy that there are many correct and respect users....Don't worry for upvotes :-))) I am happy that there is also another good user like you.